# How to pass the HH subband of an image to greycomatrix function?

Tags: python, opencv, feature-extraction, scikit-image, glcm

I'm using scikit-images's function `greycomatrix`, to which I want to give as input one of the components obtained from wavelet transform after haar filtering.

```
import pywt
import cv2
from skimage.feature import greycomatrix

original = cv2.imread('img.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
coeffs2 = pywt.dwt2(original, 'haar')
LL, (LH, HL, HH) = coeffs2
cv2.imshow('image', HH)
gCoMat = greycomatrix(HH, [2], [0], 256, symmetric=True, normed=True)
```

If I pass `HH` to `greycomatrix` I get this error:

> ValueError: Float images are not supported by greycomatrix. Convert the image to an unsigned integer type.

I tried to convert the image using this code:

```
from skimage import util

im = util.img_as_ubyte(HH)
im /= 32
gCoMat = greycomatrix(im, [2], [0], 256, symmetric=True, normed=True)
```

But I got this error:

> raise ValueError("Images of type float must be between -1 and 1.")
>   ValueError: Images of type float must be between -1 and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rescale the intensity to the range `[0, 1]` before converting the image to 8-bit unsigned integer:

```
from skimage import util, exposure, data
import pywt
from skimage.feature import greycomatrix

original = data.camera()
LL, (LH, HL, HH) = pywt.dwt2(original, 'haar')
HH_scaled = exposure.rescale_intensity(HH, out_range=(0, 1))

bin_width = 32
im = util.img_as_ubyte(HH_scaled)
im_binned = im//bin_width

gCoMat = greycomatrix(im_binned, distances=[2], angles=[0], 
                      levels=256//bin_width, symmetric=True, normed=True)
```

Notice that if the image passed to `graycomatrix` is binned, then the `levels` parameter should not be `256`, you have to divide this value by the same factor (`32` in your code). It is also important to point out that intensity binning has to be carried out through integer division (`//`), otherwise the `dtype` of `im_binned` would be `float`. As a final caveat, you have to pass `as_gray=True` to the function `io.imread`, otherwise you'll get the following error when trying to compute the grey level co-occurrence matrix:

> ValueError: The parameter `image` must be a 2-dimensional array

Comment: But it produces this error :ValueError: The parameter `image` must be a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: It will be really helpful if you can suggest me an edit